# Does Google Place API search work with partial names?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I need to do a search with partial name but no results are being returned for this example :

You can include a name parameter to match against the names of Places only. The Places API supports partial name matching, so Amo will match Amoeba.

```
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?name=amo&location=37.787930,-122.4074990&radius=5000&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Anyone get this to work.  Not sure if it isn't supported or I am doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say this returns no results; do you mean you get no data or that you get an empty results array?

Comment: This is what I get - empty results.  If I put the full name of a place it returns results matching the full name :   {
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}

Answer (score 0):

The URL in your question is malformed; try the following instead:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?name=amo&location=37.787930,-122.4074990&radius=5000&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Comment: Sorry about that...I had that but when I added the code to the question it got modified.  This is what wasn't working unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the [search](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) requests are well suited to partial words.  You may have better luck with [autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete) requests.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a poke around the API on another project I've been working with, given that your request is returning a result (albeit an empty one), I would surmise that a three character search term is probably what is causing the issue, and that you have not made any errors. I've had problems before getting short search terms to work, and I suspect (but cannot prove) that it is some kind of optimisation that google do to prevent requests that return large numbers of meaningless results (in the same way that a standard Google searches ignore words like "the").

Comment: This is from the Google Academy : https://developers.google.com/places/training/additional-places-features      

Including Names in Place Searches

You can include a name parameter to match against the names of Places only. The Places API supports partial name matching, so Amo will match Amoeba.


I am expecting that the search would show all results starting with the name given....so if the user types Amo in the input box a place like Amoeba should be returned.   Now the user has to know the exact spelling of the name and type Amoeba to find the correct place.

Comment: Well, I can't comment on that, I was merely commenting based on previous experience.